# Pushout in an abelian category

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra

Let $s':P\to T$ and $t':P\to S$ be two morphisms in an abelian category. We consider their pushout square and factor the horizontal sides using the first isomorphism theorem:

[image]

where the middle vertical arrow is induced from the universal property of kernels (using that $\operatorname{im} s=\ker(\operatorname{coker} s)$), and the left square commutes due to the fact that $\operatorname{im}s$ is monic.

**Is the left square above also a pushout? If so, why?**

Comment: The $s$ and $t$ in the embedded image are arranged in a pullback rather than a pushout configuration. So are you asking about pullbacks or pushouts?

Comment: @VladimirSotirov you mean about the primes? In any case, yes. I mean precisely what I wrote. (Observe that I took the pushout of s' and t', not of s and t. In other words, I suppose the large rectangle to be a pushout, not a pullback.)

Comment: If I'm not wrong, this lemma https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/08N4 implies that the answer to your question is yes, bu not only that: it seems they are also pullback squares.

Comment: @fosco I don't really see how :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\require{AMScd}$I'll try my best to use your notation.

Consider the span

$$\begin{CD}
P @>s'>> T \\ 
@Vt'VV @. \\ 
S
\end{CD}$$

factored as follows:

$$\begin{CD}
P @>c(s')>> I' @>i(s')>> T\\ 
@Vt'VV @. \\ 
S
\end{CD}$$

where $c(-) = \text{coim}$ and $i(-)=\text{im}$. Now form the pushouts

$$\begin{CD}
P @>c(s')>> I' @>i(s')>> T\\ 
@Vt'VV @VVV @VVV \\ 
S @>>u> Q @>>v> M
\end{CD}$$

Your question is equivalent to: "is $Q$ isomorphic to $I$, and the factorization $S \to I \to M$ isomorphic to $S\to Q \to M$?"

The answer seems to be yes: first of all notice that the universal property of the pushout $Q$ yields a unique map $Q\to I$; we aim to show that this map is invertible.

Observe that the factorization $P\to I'\to T$  of $s'$ is just the epi-mono factorization of $s'$, and epimorphisms are stable under pushout; so $u$ is an epimorphism.

If we show that $v$ is a monomorphism, we have an epi-mono factorization of $S\to M$, that must be isomorphic to the epi-mono factorization $A \xrightarrow{c(s)} I \xrightarrow{i(s)} M$ of $s$, because such a factorization is unique up to isomorphism (if you have two $(\cal E,M)$-factorizations of the same map, use orthogonality to show that there is an isomorphism between the factoring objects).

But in an abelian category, monomorphisms are *also* stable under pushout, so we're done: since $i(s')$ is a mono, $v$ is a mono. So, we're done. $\square$

---

This is not relevant to your question, but the two squares obtained in this fashion are not only pushouts, but also pullbacks (lacking a consensus on the terminology, I called them "pullouts" when I had to study them, A.2.3 [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2005.14295.pdf)): this is the content of the [Stacks lemma](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/08N4) I mentioned.

Points to keep in mind: the coim/im factorization in an abelian category $\cal A$ corresponds to the epi-mono factorization; this factorization is pushout and pullback stable, because pushouts where a leg is monic are also pullbacks, and pullbacks where a leg is epic are also pushouts; a distinguishing feature of abelianity is this self-duality (*pullback iff pushout* is *the* way in which $\infty$-/homotopy coherent notions of abelianness are stated); this reduction is very powerful: for example, it proves in a one-liner the fact that [the heart of a t-structure is abelian](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2005.14295.pdf#page=78).

Comment: Dear @fosco, I'm sorry I took so long to see (and accept) your answer. I was sick, so I couldn't really work. I also found another way to prove it, which I'll post below. And I found your thesis absolutely delightful!

Answer (score 1):

I eventually found another way to prove this result, so I'll write it here. I was interested in this question due to the proposition below, which I'll prove in its entirety. (The corollary 6.3.4 which appears is the tag 08N4 on the Stacks Project.)

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]